# How to make dependent lists in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

The task is to make dependent lists in *ComboBox*. If I select a putt in the first list of `UiComponents`, then the second list should select items from the list `geek_list1` , if I select the second item, then from `geek_list2`.

But this does not happen and `UiComponents2` is not filled.

Are there any variants how to make dependent lists in *PyQT ComboBox*?

My code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # setting title
    self.setWindowTitle("Python ")

    # setting geometry
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

    # calling method
    self.UiComponents()
    self.UiComponents2()

    # showing all the widgets
    self.show()

# method for widgets
def UiComponents(self):
    # creating a combo box widget
    combo_box = QComboBox(self)

    # setting geometry of combo box
    combo_box.setGeometry(200, 100, 120, 30)

    # geek list
    geek_list = ["Geek", "Geeky Geek", "Legend Geek", "Ultra Legend Geek"]

    # adding list of items to combo box
    combo_box.addItems(geek_list)

def UiComponents2(self):
    # creating a combo box widget
    combo_box = QComboBox(self)

    # setting geometry of combo box
    combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 120, 30)

    # geek list
    geek_list1 = ["Geek1", "Geeky Geek1", "Legend Geek1", "Ultra Legend Geek1"]
    geek_list2 = ["Geek2", "Geeky Geek2", "Legend Geek2", "Ultra Legend Geek2"]

    # adding list of items to combo box
    if self.UiComponents() == "Geek":
        combo_box.addItems(geek_list1)

    if self.UiComponents() == "Geeky Geek":
        combo_box.addItems(geek_list2)



# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())`
```

I tried doing it via `if self.UiComponents()` conditions , but `UiComponents2` doesn't see which choice is made.

Comment: It "doesn't see" because: 1. `UiComponents()` is just a function that creates widgets; 2. it doesn't check nor return nothing, so using it with an `if` is completely pointless; 3. when `UiComponents2()` is called the window is not even shown yet. Calling the first function again is also completely wrong, since it would create another combobox. It seems like you're missing important concepts of programming and Qt ( most importantly signals), so I strongly suggest you to do proper research on the topic starting from some tutorials [like this](//pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-signals-slots-events)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with the help of a dictionary. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(693, 220)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.MainComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.MainComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
        self.OfComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.OfComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 152, 681, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "TestComboBox"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Choice"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # add button
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.item_label)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        # add ComboBox
        self.MainComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
        self.MainComboBox.setModel(self.model)

        self.OfComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
        self.OfComboBox.setModel(self.model)

        # add data
        for k, v in data.items():
            state = QStandardItem(k)
            self.model.appendRow(state)
            for value in v:
                city = QStandardItem(value)
                state.appendRow(city)

        self.MainComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
        self.updateItemCombo(0)

        # add ComboBox in Wiget
        layout.addWidget(self.MainComboBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.OfComboBox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def updateItemCombo(self, index):
        indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.MainComboBox.rootModelIndex())
        self.OfComboBox.setRootModelIndex(indx)
        self.OfComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def item_label(self):
        text_label = self.MainComboBox.currentText()
        text_label2 = self.OfComboBox.currentText()
        self.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)

data = {
    'item 1': ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3'],
    'item 2': ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3'],
    'item 3': ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3']
}




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```